# NumPy bitwise "and" fails for int32 & long, but not for long & int32; why?

Tags: windows, python-2.7, numpy, long-integer, bitwise-operators

Compare this:

```
>>> import numpy; numpy.int32(-1) & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000

TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs
could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

With this:

```
>>> import numpy; 0xFFFFFFFF00000000 & numpy.int32(-1)

18446744069414584320L
```

Are both working as intended or is at least one of them a bug? Why does it occur?

Comment: Both produces TypeError with numpy 1.11.1 and 1.12.1.

Comment: With 1.6.2, the first gives `18446744069414584320L` but the second: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'long' and 'numpy.int32'`.

Comment: @kennytm: Not what I see on my 1.12.1... are you on Windows?

Comment: @Mehrdad macOS, Python 2.7.13. Check your `numpy.__version__`?

Comment: @kennytm: I already did, that's how I told you it's 1.12.1...

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in which object's `__and__` or `__rand__` method is being called.  Normally, the left-hand expression has it's `__and__` called *first*.  If it returns `NotImplemented`, then the right hand expression will get a chance (and `__rand__` will be called).

In this case, `numpy.int32` has decided that it cannot be "anded" with a long -- At least not with a long whose value is above what can be represented by native types...

However, based on your experiments, python's `long` is happy to "and" with a `numpy.int32` -- Or, possibly your version of numpy did not implement `__rand__` symmetrically with `__and__`.  This is possibly also python version dependent (e.g if your version of python decided to return a value rather than `NotImplemented`).

On my computer, neither work:

```
Python 2.7.12 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:43:17) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.__version__
'1.11.2'
```

But we can see what is being called using the following script:

```
import sys
import numpy

class MyInt32(numpy.int32):
    def __and__(self, other):
        print('__and__')
        return super(MyInt32, self).__and__(other)

    def __rand__(self, other):
        print('__rand__')
        return super(MyInt32, self).__and__(other)


try:
    print(MyInt32(-1) & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000)  # Outputs `__and__` before the `TypeError`
except TypeError:
    pass

try:
    print(0xFFFFFFFF00000000 & MyInt32(-1))  # Outputs `__rand__` before the `TypeError`
except TypeError:
    pass

sys.maxint & MyInt32(-1)  # Outputs `__rand__`
print('great success')

(sys.maxint + 1) & MyInt32(-1)  # Outputs `__rand__`
print('do not see this')
```

Comment: You might also want to try `import numpy; print(numpy.int32(1) & 0xABCD1234EFL)` btw... this long is outside the 32-bit range too.

Comment: @Mehrdad -- Yeah, that's interesting.  Likely it casts both up to `int64`.  At some point there isn't a quick way to do the `&` using native types and that's probably the point where `numpy` refuses to do the computation.

Comment: Do you know what the intended behavior is? Is this something we should rely on working (or not working) in future releases?

Comment: @Mehrdad -- Based on the fact that the numpy people went to all that work to raise a `TypeError` in one case (and because `&` _should_ be symmetric), I'm guessing that you should probably take the safe approach and assume that it is expected.  That's _my_ guess.  Note that (IIRC) anything above `0xFFFFFFFF` won't contribute anyway so you can always `&` your long with that before you `&` with your numpy array...